# Homology of the fixed points of the singular complex of a G-space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I posted the following to stackexchange a while ago [1], without any answers. Maybe the question is too unmotivated, but it seems very natural to me.

Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $G$ a finite group acting on it. We can form the singular complex $C_\bullet(X),$ and then taking homology gives singular homology: $H_*(X) = h_* C_\bullet(X).$ Since $X$ comes with a $G$-action, we could look at the fixed points of this action: $H_*(X^G) = H_* C_\bullet(X^G).$ By functoriality of the singular complex, $C_\bullet(X)$ also affords a $G$-action, and we can take its fixed point homology: $H'_* = h_* (C_\bullet(X)^G).$ Finally, we could also take the fixed points in homology: $H_*(X)^G.$

**My question is:** how does $H'_*$ (homology of the fixed points of the singular complex) relate to other more typical invariants of $X,$ such as e.g. the ones displayed above ($H_*(X),$ $H_*(X^G),$ $H_*(X)^G$)?

[1] https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743455/homology-of-the-fixed-points-of-the-singular-complex-of-a-g-space

Comment: I guess one should write $C_\bullet(X)^G=Hom_{{\mathbb Z }G}({\mathbb Z},C_\bullet(X))$, use a projective resolution of $\mathbb Z$, analyse the resulting double complex.